# Is it possible to create a community plot using ggraph?

Tags: partitioning, network-analysis, ggraph

I want to create a community plot in ggraph. Is this possible?

I made a version of it using the base plot function and igraph. Not sure how I can do this using ggraph.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the ggforce package contains geom_mark_x() geoms that can be applied to ggraph networks. geom_mark_hull() looks closest to your example.

for example:

```
gr <- as_tbl_graph(highschool) |>
mutate(
     feat1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n(), replace = TRUE),
     feat2 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], n(), replace = TRUE)
   ) |>
   mutate_at(vars(feat1, feat2), as.factor)

ggraph(gr, layout='kk', circular=F) + 
 geom_mark_hull(aes(x,y,fill=feat1)) + 
 geom_node_point() + 
 geom_node_text(aes(label=name)) + 
 geom_edge_link()
```

the fill aesthetic determines which color each node gets!